# How to take not values from column of different rows in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can anyone help me out on the below requirement with SQL:

Table having data as follows:

```
Identifier  brand   brand1  sub_brand
13          ABC     DEF     NULL
13          ABC     NULL    DEF
```

Expected result should be:

```
Identifier  brand   brand1  sub_brand
13          ABC     DEF     DEF
```

The first two columns will always contain the same values but other columns will have data in one row only. I need some generic SQL as in actual case I have many more columns.

Comment: 1) Please don't use pictures to display your data, I wouldn't be hard for you to just paste it in and format it, read [this to understand why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 2) Please don't tag DB's you are not using, tag only the one you actually use, you will get the attention needed anyway.

Comment: you can use max() and group by to get data

Comment: Thanks!...@LudvigRydahl...Have posted first time on forum...will do the same next time.

Comment: max() of column worked for me...Thanks!. @krishnpatel

Answer (score 2):

As long as you only have one value in each column you care about, then max and group by should do what you want.  If you have more than one, then I misunderstood the question.

Group by the first two columns, select max of each other column, as below

```
select ID, brand, MAX(brand1), MAX(subbrand)

from
(
select 13 as ID, 'ABC' as brand, 'DEF' as brand1, NULL as subbrand
union all select 13 as ID, 'ABC' as brand, NULL as brand1, 'DEF' as subbrand
) as testdata

group by ID, brand
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT  Identifier ,
        MAX(Brand) [Brand] ,
        MAX(Brand1) [Brand1] ,
        MAX(Sub_Brand) [Sub Brand]
FROM    Brands
GROUP BY Identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ( Identifier)  , max (brand ) as brand,max (brand1) as brand1 ,
 case  when max(sub_brand )is null  then max (brand1 )end as sub_brand
  from test  
where  brand1 is not null
   group by Identifier,sub_brand
```

Comment: Tested in my local you can try it out .

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Identifier INT,  
    brand          varchar(20),
    brand1         varchar(20),
    sub_brand     varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 
    13,'ABC','DEF',NULL UNION 
SELECT 
    13,'ABC',NULL,'DEF'

SELECT 
        a.Identifier AS Identifier,
        a.Brand AS Brand,
        a.brand1 AS brand1,
    b.sub_brand AS sub_brand
From
    #Temp a
CROSS apply
    #Temp b
WHERE 
    a.Identifier = b.Identifier
AND
    a.brand1 = b.sub_brand
```

Comment: I suggest you test this. It will return zero rows.

Comment: This will not. I have updated query for more precise solution.

Comment: Aah I see you've used the exact same sample data as OP (unfortunately a very poor example). It's unlikely `brand1` and `sub_brand` will always be the same. In which case the `a.brand1 = b.sub_brand` is counter-productive. PS: as per text of question you should include `a.brand = b.brand`

Comment: Your answer is fixable if you use appropriate sub-queries in place of `#Temp a` and `#Temp b`